# Psych to_yaml do not replace array of string

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

I am doing some replacements in a kubernetes deployment file using a ruby script and the YAML functionality. My issue now is that the following string:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-name
    image: my-image
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", "/bin/start.sh"]
```

gets turned into

```
spec:
    containers:
    - name: container-name
      image: my-image
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
      - "/bin/bash"
      args:
      - "-c"
      - "/bin/start.sh"
```

when I call `.to_yaml` on it.

I need to preserve the `[]` for `command` and `args`. Is there a way around `.to_yaml` replacing the square brackets when the content of the "array" consists only of strings (since I want - for example - an array of ports to be turned into a yaml array)?

Comment: What do you mean? `- value` is the yml representation of an `Array` can you please explain why this causes and issue?

Comment: There are no arrays in YAML, only sequences. both `["/bin/bash"]` and `- "/bin/bash"` are valid and equivalent representations of a YAML sequence. Implementations are forbidden to treat them differently. What's your problem with it?

Comment: Per the above comments: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=inline%3A+%5B+a1%2C+a2+%5D%0Ablock%3A%0A++-+b1%0A++-+b2&type=json

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I have no problem with either of them, I guess I am just not sure if K8S would handle them the same way in this specific situation ( `command` and `args`), since I can not remember seing this being written in the YAML representation (meaning `- "/bin/bash"`) anywhere.